# why is only one row being returned from the mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
mysql_query( "SELECT tre.TrainerEducationID, tge.EducationName, tre.EducationNote
              FROM trainereducation tre
              INNER JOIN trainingeducation tge ON 
                (tre.EducationID = tge.EducationID)
              WHERE tre.TrainerID = '$id'" );
```

It apparently is only returning a single row, even though there are more than 2 rows in the TrainerEducation table.
Why is that?
Shouldn't it return more than one row?

Comment: How are you fetching the rows? You need to fetch each row until it returns false, then you know there are no more rows.

Comment: ohhh  i c, so each fetch gets only one row? and each row is the array?

Comment: that is correct - please see the solution I posted.

Comment: Don't forget to use `$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id)` to protect against SQL-injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Then use:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // keep fetching until it returns false
    var_dump($row);
}
```

As posted on:
http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: i c, so each fetch call, only gets one row of the resultset?

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array does fetch one row only. Try doing it in a loop like this:

```
$all_rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $all_rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your conditions don't match, try using `left join` instead for debugging and see what you get